# How can i can keep my divs from resizing when i add/remove text?

Tags: html, css, resize

I have a table with a lot of records and a search box

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="col-3">name1</td>
        <td class="col-3">sName1</td>
        <td class="col-3">age1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="col-3">name..</td>
        <td class="col-3">sName..</td>
        <td class="col-3">age..</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="col-3">nameN</td>
        <td class="col-3">sNameN</td>
        <td class="col-3">ageN</td>
      </tr>
 </table>
```

---

```
.col-3{
   width:33,33%
}
```

Some of the records may be displayed as none, so if the search box returns a full "none" column it gets wraped to none as if it didnt have the "witdh:33,33%" atribute.

Anyone knows a way to keep the elements in his original size even if they dont have content?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `table-layout: fixed` along with a fixed width for the table

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
}
.col-3 {
  width: 33, 33%;
  border: 1px solid grey;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="col-3">name1 askdlhaslkdhsaldsad asjd;kadaj as;dj;asjd as ;asjsd;asjd;ja</td>
    <td class="col-3">sName1</td>
    <td class="col-3">age1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="col-3">name..</td>
    <td class="col-3">sName..</td>
    <td class="col-3">age..</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="col-3">nameN</td>
    <td class="col-3">sNameN</td>
    <td class="col-3">ageN</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score -1):

try this one:

```
<table style="border:1px solid">
    <tr>
        <td style="min-width:50px">one</td>
        <td style="min-width:100px">two</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```